# Post request isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

This is the html button. Currently I have the below javascript, using jquery trying to submit this form. This seems to not be working.

```
$.post(window.location,"submit");
```

And the HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Buy Now" data-theme="d">
```

Comment: well it'd be very bad if it HAD worked...

Comment: Where did you find that syntax?

Comment: DId my answer help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Is it in a form?

If so...do this...

```
    <form id='yourForm' action='' method='post'>
       <input id='submit' type="submit" value="Buy Now" data-theme="d">
    </form>
```

JQUERY

```
    $('#submit').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $('#yourForm').submit();
    });
```

Or if you wanna do it with $.post/ AJAX...

```
   $.post('urltogoto',$('#yourForm').serialize());
```

Or in context of clicking the button to submit it via AJAX...

```
   $('#submit').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var form = $('#yourForm').serialize();
       var url = 'your_url_to_post_to.php';
       $.post(url,form,function(data){
            // Do something on success of form submission
       });
    });
```

Or instead of attaching a click event, you could attach a submit event to the form itself.

```
   $( "#yourForm" ).submit(function(e) {
     // Stop form from submitting normally
     e.preventDefault();
     var form = $(this).serialize();
     var url = $(this).attr("action");
       $.post(url,form,function(data){
            // Do something on success of form submission
       });
   });
```

Comment: I was ultimately trying to submit a button from a completely different page using post.

Comment: well thats just impossible